# CustomizedComponent not connected with redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I have 2 customized component.
I put them in inside a Field so that I can save their value.
CustomizedComponent2 is connected perfectly with redux and I can take its value but CustomizedComponent1 no. Why?

```
    <div className="mainMenu">
     <form name="handleProductsForm">
              <label>Product</label>
              <Field
                component={CustomizedComponent1}
                name="products"
                items={[
                  { value: "bag", id: 1 },
                  { value: "purse", id: 2 }
                ]}
              />
              <Field component={CustomizedComponent2} name="category" type="text"/>
    </div>

    let ProductsPanel= reduxForm({
     form: "handleProductsForm",
     enableReinitialize: true
    })(ProductsPanelWrapped);

    const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
     return {
      initialValues: {
      }
     };
    };
```

Comment: please show me your redux related code

Comment: @MuhammadShaheem see my code up.

Comment: you are setting items in com1 but not in com2 why? and how would you know that com2 is connected?

Comment: @MuhammadShaheem com1 works as a dropdown which u have to choose. Com2 works as a textField which u have to insert smt. Then there is also a button which is also connected with the form with the onSubmit() method and those values from com1 and com2 should be submitted.

Comment: so you want to send items to redux store when user click submit right?

Comment: @MuhammadShaheem yes. Right now only the values from com2 is sent.

Comment: okay, First store selected values to component state and when user click submit button then dispatch an action and pass items as params

Comment: @MuhammadShaheem can u do an example?

Comment: please check hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import { yourActionName} from '../../actions/yourActionName';


onSubmit(){
  const {dispatch} = this.props
  dispatch(yourActionName(this.state.items))
} 

 // getting data from comp1 to Field

      <div className="mainMenu">
 <form name="handleProductsForm">
          <label>Product</label>
          <Field
            component={CustomizedComponent1}
            name="products"
           getItems={(items)=> this.myItems(items)}
          />
          <Field component={CustomizedComponent2} name="category" type="text"/>
</div>

 myItems(items){
  this.setState(items: items)
}


//component 1

 let {getItems} = this.props
//call this function when you selected all values 
getItems(this.state.items)
```

Comment: how the items from com1 will be connected with the state?

Comment: are you using React.Component or PureComponent ?

Comment: React.Component

Comment: are you getting items from other component to Field componnet ?

Comment: Did it helped or not?